# convert output to json in shell

Tags: bash, shell, jq

input:

```
BBAOMACBOOKAIR2?976?AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[976]:?      - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid?0700-0800?8
BBAOMACBOOKAIR2?976?AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[976]:?      - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid?0800-0900?40
BBAOMACBOOKAIR2?976?AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[976]:?      - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid?0900-1000?18
BBAOMACBOOKAIR2?976?AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[976]:?      - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid?1000-1100?14
BBAOMACBOOKAIR2?976?AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[976]:?      - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid?1100-1200?2
```

code:

`input | jq -R 'split("?")|{ deviceName:.[0], ProcessId:.[1], processName:.[2], description:.[3], timeWindow:.[4], numberOfOccurrence:.[5] }`'

error: I tried to solve it by searching Google results overnight, but I found nothing. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
split("?")|{ deviceName:.[0], ProcessId:.[1], processName:.[2], description:.[3] timeWindow:.[4], numberOfOccurrence:.[5] }                                                                                 
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 1:
split("?")|{ deviceName:.[0], ProcessId:.[1], processName:.[2], description:.[3] timeWindow:.[4], numberOfOccurrence:.[5] }
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @Barmar  Can you show me the output?

Comment: [root@localhost bash]# bash -version
GNU bash， version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[root@localhost bash]# jq --version
jq-1.6

Comment: Works for me too; outputs a bunch of individual JSON objects.

Comment: Note that the jq filter echoed in the error message is not the same as the one you provided; the one from the error is missing a comma. Which would certainly explain why that filter isn't working.

Comment: Specifically, the error message shows a missing comma after `description:.[3]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma missing between the fields "description" and "timeWindow".  The `jq` error msg reflects the typo:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
split("?")|{ deviceName:.[0], ProcessId:.[1], processName:.[2], description:.[3] timeWindow:.[4], numberOfOccurrence:.[5] }                                                                                 
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 1:
split("?")|{ deviceName:.[0], ProcessId:.[1], processName:.[2], description:.[3] timeWindow:.[4], numberOfOccurrence:.[5] }
```

Your code example has the comma & works for us!